# How to feed the multi sparse matrix into the graph

Tags: tensorflow

I have 3600 sparse matrix,dims is [14,25500], how can i feed it into the graph, except stacking these matrix into [14*3600,25500]?

Comment: When you say sparse, do you mean one-hot encoding? What are these matrices for?

Comment: yes， these matrices are the one-hot encoding, these matrices are used for the feature representation. One sentence are characterized as a matrix with dimension (14,25500)